# Элементы списка списков разнести по двум спискам python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Есть список списков формата:

```
[[(98, 0.454453), (678, 0.563333),(129, 0.879905)],
[(554, 0.769977), (28, 0.123533),(243, 0.986533)]]
```

Необходимо данные, находящиеся до пробела и запятой, отнести к `list1`,
а данные после пробела отнести к `list2`.

Как это лучше сдeлать?

Результат должен быть такой:

```
list1=[98,678,129,554,28,243]
list2=[0.454453, 0.563333, 0.879905, 0.769977, 0.123533, 0.986533]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, можно так (Простой вариант записи):

```
lsts = [[(98, 0.454453), (678, 0.563333),(129, 0.879905)], [(554, 0.769977), (28, 0.123533),(243, 0.986533)]]

list1 = []
list2 = []

for i in lsts:
    for j in i:
        list1.append(j[0])
        list2.append(j[1])
        
print(list1)
print(list2)
```

Вывод:

```
[98, 678, 129, 554, 28, 243]
[0.454453, 0.563333, 0.879905, 0.769977, 0.123533, 0.986533]
```

Для сохранения структуры списков можно немного переписать содержимое цикла, а то есть внутри нового списка добавлять список с каждой итерацией и записывать в него данные:

```
for k, i in enumerate(lsts):
    list1.append([])
    list2.append([])
    for j in i:
        list1[k].append(j[0])
        list2[k].append(j[1])
```

Вывод:

```
[[98, 678, 129] , [554, 28, 243]]
[[0.454453, 0.563333, 0.879905], [0.769977, 0.123533, 0.986533]]
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, невероятно просто и понятно)

Comment: А как сделать так чтобы структура списка списков сохранялась

Comment: @Anna Просто, я дополню ответ

Comment: Спасибо, хороший способ!

Answer (score 3):

А на выходе обязательно списки? Вот кортежи, например:

```
lists = [[(98, 0.454453), (678, 0.563333),(129, 0.879905)],
[(554, 0.769977), (28, 0.123533),(243, 0.986533)]]

list1, list2 = zip(*sum(lists, []))
print(list1, list2, sep='\n')
```

Вывод:

```
(98, 678, 129, 554, 28, 243)
(0.454453, 0.563333, 0.879905, 0.769977, 0.123533, 0.986533)
```

Только для больших списков метод с `sum` медленно работает.

А так то можно и в списки перевести, но код чуть длиннее:

```
list1, list2 = map(list, zip(*sum(lists, [])))
```

Comment: Последний вариант кода я бы отнёс к хардкору) но, все же, реально, интересно записывать всю логику в одну строчку.

Comment: @Tehnorobot Да, для начинающих сложновато. Но такое прикольно писать )

Comment: `sum(lists, [])` - квадратичная сложность.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy а если заменить на  `chain(*lists)`  из модуля  `itertools`  сложность будет меньше?

Comment: Да. `chain` и `chain.from_iterable` просто "проигрывают" списки один за другим без построения промежуточных списков. `sum(..., [])` строит новый список (медленно).